# Validation when import values from Excel file into database table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, validation, excel-import

I am trying to validate excel values when importing excel file to create a database table . If user again imported by mistake or make changes in the file then it must be validation on duplicate values or some criteria that if value already exists then over write that values to avoid duplication.

```
public function validatefile(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $this->rules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('import')->withErrors($validator);
    }
}

public function rules()
{
    return ['number.*.numbers' => 'required|unique:numbers'];
}
```